# (Tikz) graphics: series of pictures _outside_ beamer-style frames and overlays?

Tags: beamer, overlays

I want to create a series of related graphs, for instance, higlighting the traversal through a graph. It works nice using overlays in beamer frames.

Can I do analogous things in a normal document? Of course not an "overlay", but
side-by-side pictures where the first gives the only<1>-part of the figure as shown in the presentation, the second the only<2>-part etc.

Martin

Comment: Nope. The `beamer` class defines the primitives for incremental presentations.

Comment: ok. I guess I need to hack it myself. I had thought that it would be a natural enough wish that either tikz had a way to do that, or that someone had a package. I guess one need to mimick the ``counting mechanism'' (\beamer@slideinframe) and the <"slide number spec">-syntax. Maybe I look into it.

Comment: If the pages are otherwise empty, one might _probably_ do something like that with [background](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/background) and [xifthen](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/xifthen).

Answer (score 1):

probably like this?

### Code

```
\documentclass[parskip]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[margin=15mm]{geometry}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{xifthen}

\newcommand{\layerpic}[2]% layers, commands
{   \foreach \x in {1,...,#1}
    {   \begin{tikzpicture}
            \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\i}{\x+1}
            #2
        \end{tikzpicture}\\[1cm]
    }
}

\newcommand{\mylayer}[2]% layer, layer commands
{   \ifthenelse{\i>#1}
        {#2}
        {}
}

\begin{document}

\layerpic{4}
{   \mylayer{1}
    {   \fill[green!50!gray] (0,0) rectangle (12,4);    
    }
    \mylayer{2}
    {   \fill[red!50!gray] (6,2) ellipse (5.5 and 1.5);
    }   
    \mylayer{3}
    {   \fill[blue!50!gray] (1,1) circle (0.5);
        \fill[blue!50!gray] (11,1) circle (0.5);
        \fill[blue!50!gray] (1,3) circle (0.5);
        \fill[blue!50!gray] (11,3) circle (0.5);
    }
    \mylayer{4}
    {   \fill[yellow!50!gray] (3,0.1) --  (6,3.9) -- (9,0.1) -- cycle;
    }
}

\end{document}
```

### Result

[image]

---

**Edit 1:** Here's a command that will act differently in *beamer* and *non-beamer* documents:

### Code

```
\makeatletter
\@ifclassloaded{beamer}
  {\xdef\isbeamer{1}}
  {\xdef\isbeamer{0}}%
\makeatother

\newcommand{\layerpic}[2]% layers, commands
{ \ifthenelse{\isbeamer=1}
    {   \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.5]
            #2
        \end{tikzpicture}
    }
    {   \foreach \x in {1,...,#1}
    {   \begin{tikzpicture}
        \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\i}{\x+1}
        #2
        \end{tikzpicture}\\[1cm]
    }
  }  
}

\newcommand{\mylayer}[2]% layer, layer commands
{ \ifthenelse{\isbeamer=1} 
    {   \only<#1->{#2}
    }
    {   \ifthenelse{\i>#1}
    {#2}
    {}
  }    
}
```

### Output

In a *non-beamer* document (e.g. *scrartcl*), the output is exactly the same as before. In *beamer* however (the `tikzpicture` is scaled to `0.5` in beamer mode, as slides are only 128mm wide):

[image]

Comment: thanks, sort of. What I still need to figure out is: the figures inside the slides and in the document should be shared, i.e., use the same syntax so that I use the "overlay"-pictures in the presentation, but for the handout, the different stages are printed side by side, showing how the graph evolves.

Comment: So you want the macro to be aware if it is in a `beamer` or e.g. `article` documentclass and then use either the `beamer` overlays or the `article` steps? And if yes, do you need more complicated expressions like `<1,2-4,7->` (because this would be kind of tricky, I think)?